# Simulink Block to increase signal with a step at a certain time

Tags: matlab, simulink

I state that I have searched for a long time but I can't find an answer to my problem.
I don't find a Simulink block that has the function of giving in input one step that is worth an x (defined by me) for 5s and 1.1x from 6 to 50s at two models (one linear and one non linear systems)
Usually i use the Step Block to start an initial and final value of the step but the change is almost instantaneous. What block can I use to do this?

[image]

Comment: I don't get why the step block you use usually does not work in this case?

Comment: @thewaywewalk Because Step only gives an impulse in a determinated time. I need a step in 0 of x and anoter step in 6 of 1.1x, and probably i can't do this only with Step Block. I thought of a way, active a new Step at 6 seconds of 0.1x, I wanted to do it with a different block but if i don't find an alternative so I do.

Comment: you can use a look up table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Option 1

Use multiple step blocks and add them up. Simple as that.

### Option 2

Use the [**signal builder**](https://de.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/signalbuilder.html) block.

[image]